# Getting "warning: already initialized constant" on assets precompile at the time of cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Currently I am facing a weird warning messages on deploy:assets:precompile at production deploy through capistrano.

When I ran cap production deploy for first time deployment of my demo Rails project, getting following warning messages and deploy failed with cap aborted!

```
#<Thread:0x0000558ae4eef218@/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing on host IP: rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
rake stdout: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:66: warning: already initialized constant Net::ProtocRetryError
/home/ubuntu/apps/demo-test/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.0/lib/net/protocol.rb:66: warning: previous definition of ProtocRetryError was here
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:172: warning: already initialized constant Net::BufferedIO::BUFSIZE
/home/ubuntu/apps/demo-test/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.0/lib/net/protocol.rb:206: warning: previous definition of BUFSIZE was here
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:439: warning: already initialized constant Net::NetPrivate::Socket
/home/ubuntu/apps/demo-test/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.0/lib/net/protocol.rb:503: warning: previous definition of Socket was here
rake stderr: Nothing written
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39):

same here, it seems like a wird issue with gem dependencies
https://github.com/ruby/net-imap/issues/16

If you add `gem "net-http"` in your gem file the issue should go
This gem should anyway be already present in your gemfile.lock as a dependency

*edit*

Once you upgraded successfully, you can remove the gem from your file
This is a update dependency bug. Once updated, you are good

Comment: Adding `gem "net-http"` also worked for me. Just an extra note, according to [this](https://github.com/ruby/net-imap/issues/16#issuecomment-803086765O) comment on the issue you link to, it says the problem should go away soon if/when a dependency is altered. So we could possibly remove the net-http gem at some point in the future.

Comment: Turns out `bundler` had a dependency load issue.  So the solution above is but one of many results.  The new `bundler` has fixed this.  I will answer the question, as I've been monitoring its behaviour.

Comment: works like a charm - thanks. I was using ruby 2.7.2 and oauth2 1.4.7, that caused the warning to occur. Adding `gem "net-http"` to my gemfile did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

the updated answer from the thread linked above that worked for me was adding these to the gemfile.

```
gem "net-http"
gem "net-smtp"
gem "net-imap"
gem "uri", "0.10.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

`Bunder` was the culprit, with some dependency issues.  Update with:

```
bundle update --bundler
```

Comment: This alone didn't work for me. Should we still add `gem "net-http"` first?

Comment: Re-read what Nathan said above.  Check your `Gemfile.lock` file to see if it's called already, then use `Bundle.require`.

Comment: For me, it wasn't in Gemfile.lock. I only got the warnings when running this [zeitwerk check](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#how-to-verify-the-application-runs-in-zeitwerk-mode-questionmark). I'm not sure how important it was to fix, but for me adding `gem "net-http"` to Gemfile was sufficient.

Comment: `net-http` is not in the core, so it needs to be in your `Gemfile`.  https://rubygems.org/gems/net-http